# jquery auto-check checkbox from same table

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<table class=tbl>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class='c1' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='c2' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='c2' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='c2' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class=tbl>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class='c1' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='c2' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='c2' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='c2' type='checkbox'>
            <label>Ceckbox2</label>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $('.c2').click(function () {
     if ($(this).parent().find('.c2').is(':checked')) {
         alert('all are checked');
     } else {
         alert('none are checked');
     }
 });
```

I am trying, with no result, to use jquery to auto-check 'c1' only when all the 'c2' from the same 'tbl' are checked. The count of 'c2' can vary as can the count of 'tbl'.

Comment: i tryed this:  $('.c2').click(function(){
  if($(this).parent().find('.c2').is(':checked'))
   {
    alert('all are checked');
   }
  else
   {
    alert('none are checked');
   }

 });

Comment: @user1885099: put your code in question.

Comment: Sorry. I added the code i tryed.

Comment: Does it alert correctly?

Comment: it alerts when one of 'c2' is checked, I am trying to make it alert when all the 'c2' from the same 'tbl' are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it works:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/unNFZ/1/)

```
$('.c2').change(function(){
    var all = true;
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.c2').each(function(index){
        if(!($(this).is(':checked'))){
           all =  false;
        }
    });
    if (all==true){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.c1').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see if all the checkboxes are checked by comparing the total number of checkboxes to the number of checked boxes, within the same parent `tr`. Try this:

```
$('.c2').change(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    var allChecked = $('.c2', $parent).length === $('.c2:checked', $parent).length;
    $('.c1', $parent).prop('checked', allChecked);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wUAL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This will check if all `.c2` checkboxes on the same table are checked:

```
$('.c2').on('change', function(){
  var allCheckboxes = $(this).parents('table').find('.c2');
  var allCheckedBoxes = $(this).parents('table').find('.c2:checked');

  if(allCheckboxes.length === allCheckedBoxes.length ) {
     $(this).parents('table').find('.c1').prop('checked', true);
  }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JxCC2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.c2').click(function () {
    var $tbl = $(this).closest('.tbl');
    $tbl.find('.c1').prop('checked', $tbl.find('.c2:not(:checked)').length === 0);
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wyCdB/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 $('.c1').click(function () {
     if ($(this).parent().find('.c1').is(':checked')) {
         alert('all are checked');
         $('.tbl input').attr('checked',true);
     } else {
         alert('none are checked');
          $('.tbl input').attr('checked', false);
     }
  });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.c2').click(function () {
    var all = $(this).closest('.tbl').find('.c2'),
        checked = all.filter(':checked');
     if (all.length === checked.length) {
         alert('all are checked');
     } else {
         alert('none are checked');
     }
 });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/Q6San/